# PM2 using wrong node.js version

Tags: node.js, pm2

I had node version v6.11.1 installed but it was giving error in some package, so i installed v10.15.3 with nvm and set it as default.

```
#If I run my app directly using node, it uses correct node version v10.15.3 and works
node server.js

#If I run using pm2 it uses old node version v6.11.1 and causes error.
pm2 start server.js
```

I tried passing --interpreter like

```
pm2 start server.js --interpreter=~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node
#but even this uses v6.11.1
```

I verify the node version by printing process.version inside my app.

Answer (score 17):

For later fellow googlers:

```
pm2 update
```

did help me in a similar case.

Found here:
https://github.com/keymetrics/pm2-plus-tech-questions/issues/88

Comment: This helped me greatly. Just in case future readers, you can check which node version pm2 is using with this command: pm2 show <appId/ appName>

Comment: `pm2 monit ` is another way to check the node version